# How to copy text with '\n' into clipboard?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My `copyTextToClipboard` works if I pass in a single line string argument.

However, it doesn't work if the string contains of '\n'.

How do get it to copy multiple lines?

```
  private getProxyList() {
    this.proxies$.subscribe(proxyList => {
      this.proxyList = proxyList.map(proxies => proxies.proxy).join('\n');
      this.copyTextToClipboard(this.proxyList);
    });
  }

  private copyTextToClipboard(val) {
    console.log(val);
    let selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.value = val;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  }
```

**EDIT:**

It has to do with my subscribe scope. I was able to console.log the data, but it failed to copy to clipboard.

If I call the function outside of subscribe, for ex: this.copyTextToClipbooard("this\nString") it works. How come I cannot copy to clipboard when inside the subscribe? how to fix this?

Comment: You may want to use the new clipboard API instead.  See here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi

Comment: Works as expected for me in Chrome. How did you test it to confirm wither or not newlines were included

Comment: @PatrickEvans check new Edit

Comment: For me it works in chrome; I've tested in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/qozamaqiba/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @V.Sambor it doesn't work if I call it inside the subscribe scope: this.proxies$.subscribe(proxyList => {
      this.proxyList = proxyList.map(proxies => proxies.proxy).join('\n');
      this.copyTextToClipboard(this.proxyList);
    });

Comment: Have you tried to use '\r\n' as Newline? It's Windows, right?

Comment: Can we see how `getProxyList` is called?